# Section 5.10 from Kernighan/Ritchie Command line arguments/optional parameters

Tags: c, optional-parameters, kernighan-and-ritchie

first time poster. Was hoping someone could help me with this. In section 5.10, Kernighan gives this example of a program that reprints lines of text with the string in them. So I saved this as "find" in my folder, and then went into cmd, then the folder, then typed find "-x whatever". Yet for some reason the '-' is not registering, and it just treats "-x whatever" as one long string. Anyone got any clues why this is happening? Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAXLINE 1000

int getline(char *s, int lim)
{
int i = 0;

while(i < lim - 1 && (*s = getchar()) != EOF && *s++ != '\n')
   i++;

if(*s == '\n')
  *s++ = '\n', i++;

*s = '\0';
return i;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

 char line[MAXLINE];
 long lineno = 0;
 int c, except = 0, number = 0, found = 0;

 while(--argc > 0 && (*++argv)[0] == '-')
    while(c = *++argv[0])
      switch(c) {
         case 'x':
              except = 1;
              break;
         case 'n':
              number = 1;
              break;
         default:
              printf("find: illegal option %c\n", c);
              argc = 0;
              found = -1;
              break;
      }

 if(argc != 1)
     printf("Usage: find -x -n pattern\n");
 else
     while(getline(line, MAXLINE) > 0) {
         lineno++;
         if((strstr(line, *argv) != NULL) != except) {
               if(number)
                  printf("%ld:", lineno);
               printf("%s", line);
               found++;
         }
     }

 printf("Found: %d", found);
 return found;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to type

```
  find -x whatever
```

instead of

```
  find "-x whatever"
```

Comment: When i type in 

    `find -x whatever`

it says FIND: Parameter format not correct. If I type 

    `find -x "whatever"`

it says File not found - -X

Comment: You might try calling your program something other than "find".  There is already a find command which you are probably invoking by mistake.

Comment: Lol. I think what I did was I did not build the program and "find" was the old command. haha. Thanks a lot guys.

Comment: You can run your own find by giving the path to it: `./find -x whatever` for example.